# Full image PNG overlay over GIF, PNG, JPG

Tags: php, gd

I want to make a full image watermark which would work on jpg, gif and png files. But
it doesn't seem to be working. My idea is having, let's say, a 1024x768 transparent PNG-8
image (doesn't really matter, I just followed [this](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2008/11/watermark-your-images-with-another.html) tutorial and there said it's 
recommended to use that), resize it to the image size I want to overlay and then merge them.
Being not so advanced with GD, I just can't make it work, however, this is my code:

```
$parts = explode('.', $filename);
$ext = $parts[count($parts)-1];

switch ($ext) {
    case 'jpg':
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir . $filename);
        break;
    case 'jpeg':
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir . $filename);
        break;
    case 'png':
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($dir . $filename);
        break;
    case 'gif':
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($dir . $filename);
        break;
}

$overlay = imagecreatefrompng($overlay);
$overlayNew = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagecolortransparent($overlayNew, imagecolorallocatealpha($overlayNew, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($overlayNew, false);
imagesavealpha($overlayNew, true);

imagecopyresized( $overlayNew , $overlay , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , imagesx($image) , imagesy($image) ,imagesx($overlay) , imagesy($overlay) );
imagecopymerge($image, $overlayNew,0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($overlayNew), imagesy($overlayNew), $opacity);

$parts = explode(".", $filename);
imagepng($image, $dir . $parts[0] . '_watermarked.png');
```

Comment: +1 for showing me "imagesx()"

Comment: Also, please post what this code IS doing and what it is doing WRONG

Comment: Ok, first we load up the image, then overlay, create a new image and
copy resized overlay into it, then merge the overlay and image.
You can see how it looks like here http://vytas.webege.com/random/
If I use 24bit PNG, JPG and PNG comes out fine, however, GIF just
comes out blank with light blue shade.

Comment: So you're saying it IS working with PNG,JPG, and PNG-24, but not GIF?  Also, consider using imagecopyresampled instead of imagecopyresized for better-quality resizing